# Spring Security | JWT authorization not working as expected | Spring-Security RequestMatchers not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am new to Spring security and trying to implement JWT authorization
But i am not getting the token string back in postman
Below is my Whole code

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder, UserDetailsService userDetailService)
            throws Exception {

        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder)
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return  http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers( HttpMethod.POST, "/authenticate").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).build(); //other URLs are only allowed authenticated users.
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder createBcryptencoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

RestController.java

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtGenerator jwtGenerator;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String welcome()
    {
        return "<h1>Welcome</h1>";
    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Into authenticate method - start");
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate
                    (new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                                    authenticationRequest.getPassword())
                            );
        } catch (BadCredentialsException exception) {
          throw new Exception("Incorrect Username and password",exception);
        }

        final UserDetails userDetails= userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        String jwtToken= jwtGenerator.generateToken(userDetails);
        System.out.println("Into authenticate method - start");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse("token"));
    }
}
```

MyUserDetailsService.java [ username- "admin" and password - "admin"

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService  implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      return new User("admin","$2a$12$bsoxyT/xhfg4punBFRk9h.zjwpa5LulQ/MLgCa07i26cYHGdvMoge",new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());

    }
}
```

JWTGenerator.java

```
@Service
public class JwtGenerator {

    private final String SECRET_KEY="secret";
    
    public String extractUsername(String token)
    {
        return extractClaim(token,Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token)
    {
        return extractClaim(token,Claims::getExpiration);
    }
    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token)
    {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims,T> claimsResolver)
    {
        final Claims claims=extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public Claims extractAllClaims(String token)
    {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails){
       Map<String,Object> claims=new HashMap<>();
       return createToken(claims,userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    public String createToken(Map<String,Object> claims, String username)
    {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .addClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000*60*60*10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256,SECRET_KEY)
                .compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token,UserDetails userDetails)
    {
         final String username= extractUsername(token);
         return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())&& !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

AuthenticationRequest.java

```
public class AuthenticationRequest {

    private String username;
    private String password;


    public AuthenticationRequest() {
    }

    public AuthenticationRequest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

AuthenticationResponse.java

```
package com.javabrains.springsecurityjwt.model;

public class AuthenticationResponse {

    private String jwtToken;

    public AuthenticationResponse(String jwtToken) {
        this.jwtToken = jwtToken;
    }

    public String getJwtToken() {
        return jwtToken;
    }

    public void setJwtToken(String jwtToken) {
        this.jwtToken = jwtToken;
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security-jwt</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Security JWT</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Spring boot version- 3.1.1

Current Response:
[Postman response 401 unauthorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUbbS.png)

1. My Expectation is that only "/authenticate" endpoint should be permitted without authentication rest all endpoints must be authenticated before using the resource,
   but i am getting 401 Unauthorized in postman even for correct username and password
2. Also i am expecting a JWT token string as response in postman

I need immediate help on this code ? Thank you in advance for helping me :)

Comment: /authenticate is POST method so you have to disable the csrf in your securityFilterChain()                 
`http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())`